# A second question about a proof of Banach-Alaoglu

Tags: functional-analysis

I have another question about the proof of Banach-Alaoglu using nets.

The proof proceeds by considering a universal net into the closed unit ball of $X^\ast$, let's call the ball $S$ and the net $\varphi_\alpha$. After applying the boundedness of $\varphi_\alpha (x)$ and Tychonov's theorem one gets a limit $\varphi (x) $.

Now I'm not sure I fully understand the proof. I thought one should find a limit $\varphi$ of the net $\varphi_\alpha$ and then show that $\varphi$ is in the closed unit ball. Now instead one ends up with $\varphi(x)$ which is just a point in $\mathbb C$. Of course one can do this arguemnt for all $x \in X$ and then claim that $\varphi (x)$ is the map resulting from this but I'm sure I'm missing something here.

Can one do this instead: by the definition of the weak star topology $\varphi_\alpha (x)$ converges to $\varphi (x)$ if and only if $\varphi_\alpha$ converges to $\varphi$? I think this would spare me showing that $\varphi$ is linear (boundedness is easy but linearity in the other argument is not obvious to me).

Comment: "Of course one can do this argument for all $x\in X$ and then claim that $\varphi(x)$ is the map resulting from this but I'm sure I'm missing something here." No, that's exactly what one does (with varying degree of detailedness). One needs to verify that the resulting map is a) linear, and b) bounded, and c) belongs to the closed unit ball of $X^\ast$, but these are all routine verifications.

Comment: @DanielFischer Is there no way around it in the way I describe later? I can't seem to show that $\varphi$ is indeed linear. So I was looking for a way of avoiding that.

Comment: Well, the existence of $\varphi$ is the whole point. You can't assume it. You immediately have the existence of a _function_ $\varphi \colon X \to \mathbb{K}$ to which $\varphi_{\alpha}$ converges pointwise. But then you need to check it has the required properties. To check the linearity, use the linearity of the $\varphi_\alpha$ and the linearity of limits. $$\varphi (rx + sy) = \lim_\alpha \varphi_\alpha(rx+sy) = \lim_\alpha \left(r\varphi_\alpha(x) + s\varphi_\alpha(y)\right) = \dotsc$$

Comment: @DanielFischer I guess the notation $\lim_\alpha \varphi_\alpha $ is still confusing me. I mean: $A$ is just a directed set so there is no $\infty$ in it. So the expression (that you cleverly avoided in your comment) $\lim_{\alpha \to \infty}\varphi_\alpha$ does not exist. I'll take $\lim_\alpha$ to be the (obvious) generalization of the usual limit.

Comment: $x$ is a limit of the net $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}$ if for every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ there is an index $\alpha(U)\in A$ such that $a_\alpha \in U$ for all $\alpha \geqslant \alpha(U)$. The definition is hardly distinguishable from the definition of the limit of a sequence. The thing (which doesn't appear explicitly in the definition) is that we cannot in general compare every $\alpha \in A$ to the index $\alpha(U)$. So what? We have the same "for all large enough indices, the term of the net lies in $U$". We can also denote the limit by $\lim\limits_{\alpha\to\infty}$, just like for ...

Comment: ... sequences, after all, we also have $\infty \notin \mathbb{N}$. Just like we place $\infty$ "just behind" all natural numbers, we may place an $\infty$ "just behind" all $\alpha\in A$ and define a neighbourhood of $\infty$ to contain a set of the form $N_\beta = \{\infty\} \cup \{ \alpha\in A : \alpha \geqslant\beta\}$ if we wish so. But the plain $\lim\limits_\alpha$ or $\lim\limits_{\alpha\in A}$ are more common in my experience.